# Updating List of Entity Entries of DialogFlow Agent via API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-api, dialogflow-es

Have been looking for a way to programmatically update our agent's `entity entries` for a certain `entity type` through the **DialogFlow API**. The purpose is to automate the updating of our `entity entries` on a scheduled basis (as our `entries` will be changing daily).

Came across this [documentation page by Google](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes.entities/batchUpdate) on batch updating `entity entries` but have not been able to get anything better than a `404` when testing.

Have tried sending POST's via Postman using the supplied path and inserting my project name in URL but I believe I may be making naive mistakes as I am new to this area (specifically REST-stuff)

Below is an example of the current `404` response & path used.

We are just looking to get past the `404` error, once we have the contact setup, should be able to figure out auth & the rest.

[image: Postman 404 Response]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you need to take into account.

The URL should look like this:
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/julia-development-2/agent/entityTypes/actual_id/entities:batchUpdate

- the "parent" you used in the URL is just the name of the path param
- make sure "julia-development-2" is the id of your GCP project and not just the name
  (Hint: when you click the drop-down for selecting a certain GCP project in the google cloud console, both the name and the ID of the project will be visibile in the list)
- replace "actual_id" with the entity type id

Related to auth:

- you need a bearer token in the Authorization header
- to get this token you first need to download a JSON key from your projects service account and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to your JSON file. More details about setting up the service account and downloading the JSON key, you can find here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/setup
- to get the token from the command line you can use

  gcloud auth application-default print-access-token

Comment: Thanks going to try this out!

Comment: how do I find entity type id?

Comment: @Art you need to click the download button on the entity in dialogflow console