# Update entity in dialogflow using API in Postman

Tags: api, dialogflow-es

I am using V2 version of dialogflow, I want to update one of my entry from the present entity. let suppose, I have an entity named "Language" having an entry "java", I want to update its synonym as "object-oriented language"

The API I am hitting on Postman is: 
**https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/demoproject-123/agent/entityTypes/********-****-****-****-************/entities:batchUpdate**

In the authorization header>bearer token, I am giving the token received from the cloud shell after setting the path of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path.json"

So, when I am hitting the API on postman, I am getting an error as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating List of Entity Entries of DialogFlow Agent via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762053/updating-list-of-entity-entries-of-dialogflow-agent-via-api)

Comment: Please check => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762053/updating-list-of-entity-entries-of-dialogflow-agent-via-api

Comment: I did all the procedure following the same link you have mentioned. It is not working

Comment: can you show what you are sending as body

Comment: Sure, In body>raw I am providing the following code:                                         
 {
  "entities": [
    {
      "value": "java",
      "synonyms": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: please update that in your question properly, so issue can be reproduce